# How to hide legend element based on specific year in Tableau

Tags: tableau-api, legend

I am pretty  new to Tableau and I have a question about hiding a specific element from the legend box in Tableau software. I have legend based on year (2018,2019) and measure values ( which is calculation formula for retrieving the result for the current and previous year)  for 2019 year. I would like in my legend box to hide targets for 2018(previous year).   If I exclude Target(Budget) 2018 from the legend box, it is excluding the element Cost, 2018. Could someone help me how to solve this ?

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Do2Od.png)

Comment: Instead of using the built-in color legend, create a new worksheet and make your own.

Comment: move it to bottom and cover it with floating blank

Comment: Thank you Gupta, that is a good idea.:)